# How to use JNDI in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, jndi, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Tomcat 5.5 running which includes a Webapp with the Java Reporting Components (JRC) 2008.

The Server has a different data source than the client, and currently I set it with the setConnection() functions on the tables, and it works fine. The downside is, that this taken 800ms (Damn slow crystal) just to set the datasources.

Since Crystal Reports seem to use JNDI, how do I configure JNDI in my app? Can this be done programmatically, or do I have to specify the data sources in the web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I found out for myself.

Add the Datasource to the context.xml of the Tomcat Server, and add a ref to the web.xml! Now Crystal is happyly taking this datasource and no manual relinking of datasources is needed.